# HTTP::persistent and proxy?

Tags: ruby

I have source code that uses the 'http' gem, and the line of code to initialize the connection is:

`HTTP.persistent(endpoint).headers(...).timeout(...)`

It looks a bit weird to me, and I can't find any mention of an actual `.persistent` method in HTTP. Has anyone seen this? If so, is there a way to use a proxy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the [wiki page of the HTTP gem](https://github.com/httprb/http/wiki/Persistent-Connections-%28keep-alive%29) there is mention of `.persistent`. There's also a page dedicated to proxy support.